# controlling fluid simulation shape

Tags: fluid-simulation

I want to create a basic fluid simulation , similar to [This water bottle picture](http://blogs.stlawu.edu/greenwashingcritiques/files/2014/04/PHA_DASANI-WATER_carousel_980x550_091113_for_web-fixed.jpg), however, I can't control the shape of the fluid with mere splashes of bottle with the domain set up, which is like:

[image]

It's not becoming like my target at all. How should I simulate the fluid so that my fluid becomes like the sample image I have attached above?

Edit:  As mentioned in the question below, I've tried a few straightforward tricks to achieve that effect. I used tricks because on a fb group I asked a couple of people who mentioned that achieving that effect would not be straightforward with blender as it's fluid sim is not that unique, here is my try in the blend file:

[image]

Comment: hi, complex matter, have you seen this? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/fluid/types/control.html

Comment: @m.ardito, yes but that's not a tutorial

Comment: yes but this site is not to google tutorials for you, but to help you with blender issues you have. If you have seen that, and can tell us what you tried and is not understandable or not working well... an answer will come soon, and also you, us and others will learn something cool toghether :D. you could also provide a sample file of yours (through http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then edit your question and paste the provided link) so that anybody can help you specifically on your tries...

Comment: also see https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2380/what-is-the-proper-action-for-a-question-that-requests-links-to-tutorials

Comment: @m.ardito , I added it! :-)

Comment: oh thanks, good: now I see what you're trying. But you're using an "obstacle", not "control" shape? Unfortunately my pc is quite crap and  this simulation could be heavy. Also, I'm quite leaving for some holiday, but others will jump in more easily now. As an alternative have you also considered to "sculpt" that water shape? It could be easier to reproduce, maybe...

Comment: @m.ardito , thanks for that, never did anything but manual modelling and sculpting, so thought I'd try increasing my knowledge towards simulations and physics.(And all that modelling with tiny details, droplets and thinness of water would so much get tiresome)